# How to call an activity before screen lock is shown?

Tags: android

I want to start an activity even before screen lock after rebooting. here is my code

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.bootservicestartup.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".BootUpReceiver">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>


</application>

public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);

}
```

what the code does is when the phone is rebooted, an activity will be shown. that works. but I also want the activity to be shown even before showing the screen lock.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you if you did it as a service;

You need the following in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

1) In your  element:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

2) In your  element (be sure to use a fully-qualified [or relative] class name for your BroadcastReceiver):

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

(you don't need the android:enabled, exported, etc., attributes... the Android defaults are correct)

In MyBroadcastReceiver.java:

```
package com.example;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: problem with that the activity launches after the screen lock. I want the activity to be show before viewing the screen lock?

Comment: service works if screen locked or not, but you can add this tag to your layout
android:keepScreenOn="true"
or
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

this will grantee that the screen will not locked